# pushwoosh Custom Push Broadcast Receiver not fire when application is close

Tags: android, pushwoosh

I have created Custom Push Broadcast Receiver for handle push notification and save notification in local database,but in my app custom receiver not fire when new notification arrive and app is close.

I want to save notification in database when app is close and notification arrives.

Please suggest and help me.

Comment: did you follow the official docs properly? the codes provided in the documentation are working and tested obviously.

Comment: yes, i used official docs for this, and it's working fine when i am clicking on notification, but when notification arrives and just clear it then custom receiver not fire.

Comment: you want to save the notification data when the notification arrives or onclick on the notification? and if the app is not use even the notification arrives.  you should write your db code in broadcastreceiver. [HERE](https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-native-samples/blob/master/Android/src/com/pushwoosh/test/tags/sample/app/SilentPushReceiver.java)

Comment: looking for the solution still ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to write broadcastreceiver like this and register it manifest so whenever the notification will arrives this receiver will take action.

```
 public class PushWooshManager extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("PUSH", "received");
        if (intent!=null){
        write your code to store the notification data

    }
}
```

Comment: I have created this and reg. in manifest as follows    


 <receiver
            android:name=".receivers.NotificationReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="PW_NOTIFICATION_RECEIVER"
            android:value="com.che.pushDemo.receivers.NotificationReceiver" />

Comment: so what you want to do actually?